# Deformed circle drawn with Cos and Sin math functions Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, line, angle

I want the purple circle, seen below, to be rotated like in the 2nd image.

[image]

[image]

The problem - as you can see - is that the circle gets deformed. I have an idea why,

This is the code for the first image,

```
Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (radius * Mathf.Cos (theta), radius * Mathf.Sin (theta), 0f);
```

I switched the 2nd argument with the 3rd, and it *sort of* worked (as you saw, the purple circle got deformed).

```
Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (radius * Mathf.Cos (theta), 0f, radius * Mathf.Sin (theta));
```

---

```
private void Circle() {
    lineRenderer.widthMultiplier = lineWidth;

    float deltaTheta = (2f * Mathf.PI) / vertexCount;
    float theta = 0f;

    lineRenderer.positionCount = vertexCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < lineRenderer.positionCount; i++) {
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (radius * Mathf.Cos (theta), 0f, radius * Mathf.Sin (theta));
        lineRenderer.SetPosition (i, pos);
        theta += deltaTheta;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your transform's scale. The x and z scales will be unequal, causing this problem.

Comment: Ahhh yes indeed! Silly me, the black rectangle has its scale deformed.